# NodeJS process exit, buffer requests until restart

Tags: node.js, nginx

Loving node but I have a question about making my application more fault tolerant. I like to assume the worst so lets assume my application has a fault that leads to application exit every now and then. PM2 or your preferred monitor will reboot it but some requests may fail while it restarts / before load balancers detect its down.

Are there any good containers or tools I can put in front of node to buffer these requests (for a reasonable amount of time) until the app bootstraps and comes back online? Perhaps Nginx can do this?

Comment: Here's some relevant information: http://serverfault.com/questions/551339/buffer-requests-to-nginx-for-a-short-time-if-backend-is-down